# System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher ReferralChasing and PageSize together

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap, directorysearcher

I was wondering why `ReferralChasing` and `PageSize` cannot be used together with `System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher`?

This code, without `PageSize`, will chase referrals and show me all accounts:

```
[System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry] $objRoot = New-Object [System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("GC://DC=comapny,DC=com")
[System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher] $objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($objRoot)

$objSearcher.SearchScope = "Subtree"
$objSearcher.ReferralChasing = "All"
$objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange("name,distinguishedName".split(","))

$objSearcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(memberOf=CN=one,OU=two,OU=three,DC=dingo,DC=company,DC=com))"
$objSearcher.FindAll()
```

But this code, with `PageSize` will not show me all accounts.

```
[System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry] $objRoot = New-Object [System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("GC://DC=comapny,DC=com")
[System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher] $objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($objRoot)

$objSearcher.SearchScope = "Subtree"
$objSearcher.ReferralChasing = "All"
$objSearcher.PageSize = 1000
$objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange("name,distinguishedName".split(","))

$objSearcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(memberOf=CN=one,OU=two,OU=three,DC=dingo,DC=company,DC=com))"
$objSearcher.FindAll()
```

For the sake of this question, the account it will not show me is "`CN=user,OU=some,OU=folder,DC=bingo,DC=company,DC=com`". Notice how the account is in a different DC.

Comment: Is there a trust between the domains?

Comment: Yes. It works if `PageSize` is not there so I am not sure why it would stop just by adding `PageSize`.

Comment: Have you tried with a smaller `PageSize`?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't matter what size I use; if `PageSize` is set then referrals are not chased and nothing is retuned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had cross posted this on the MSDN forums and got an answer. To quote the answer from their:

> According to documentation for ReferralChasing, “All” includes
>   “Subordinate”, and “the ADSI LDAP provider always turns off this flag
>   for paged searches” for some reasons
>   [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.referralchasingoption?view=netframework-4.7.1].

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4f2e4f81-a581-4006-a85f-218cb55a7b8a/systemdirectoryservicesdirectorysearcher-referralchasing-and-pagesize-together?forum=netfxbcl